# javascript with buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a unit conversion program. I have everything working except for my calculate function and where the answer is being displayed. All i need help on is how to calculate each other the conversions, and to display the answer in a empty textbox that is below the calculate button. here is my code.

```js
function showSecond() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked){
        div1.style.display = "block";
        div.style.display = "none";
        div2.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].checked){
        div1.style.display = "none";
        div.style.display = "block";
        div2.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        div1.style.display = "none";
        div.style.display = "none";
        div2.style.display = "block";
    }
}
function Calc()
{
    var amt = document.getElementsByName(amount)    
    var res = document.getelementsByName(fin)
    if (document.getElementsByName("rad2")[0].checked) {
        var ch = amt * 2.2;
        document.write(fin) = ch;
    }
    else {
        res = amt / 2.2;
        document.write(res)
    }
```

```html
Select Conversion Type: 
<br />
<input type = "radio" name = "rad1" onclick= "showSecond()" />Length
<br />
<input type = "radio" name = "rad1" onclick = "showSecond()" />Weight
<br />
<input type = "radio" name = "rad1" onclick = "showSecond()" />Volume
<br />

<div id = "div" style="display:none">
    Select Direction:
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad2" value="PG" />Pounds to Kgs
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad2" value="KP" />Kgs to Pounds
    <br />
    Number to be converted: <input type = "text" name = "amount" />
    <br />
    <input type = "button" value = "calculate" onclick = "Calc()" /> 
    <br />
    <input type ="text" name ="fin" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
</div>

<div id = "div1" style="display:none">
    Select Direction:
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad3" value="FM" />Feet to meters
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad3" value="MF" />Meters to Feet
    <br />
    Number to be converted: <input type = "text" name = "amount" value=""/>
    <br />
    <input type = "button" value = "calculate" onclick = "Calc()" /> 
    <br />
    Result: <br />
    <input type="text" name ="fin" value ="" readonly="readonly"/>
 </div>

<div id = "div2" style="display:none">
    Select Direction:
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad4" value="GL" />Gallons to Liters
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad4" value="LG" />Liters to Gallons
    <br />
    Number to be converted: <input type = "text" name = "amount" />
     <br />
    <input type = "button" value = "calculate" onclick = "Calc()"> 
    <br />
    Result: <br />
    <input type ="text" name = "fin"  value="" readonly="readonly"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Well you are using document.write instead of setting a form field value. Looks like you should try to figure that out.

Comment: Your `Calc` function is missing its closing brace.  Or maybe that's just a typo here?

Comment: it was a typo. but i'm still unable to get it to workout.

Comment: i'm not allowed to use forms for this.

Answer (score 1):

*Tried to run in JSFiddle and couldn't get it to work the way I want but eh might just be on my side or maybe I did something wrong*

What I would do:
 Make the button's have different ID's such as:

`<input type = "button" id="weightCalculate" value = "calculate" onclick = "Calc(this)" />`

Something like so:

```
  Select Conversion Type:
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" id="length" name = "rad1" onclick="showSecond(this)" />Length
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" id="weight" name = "rad1" onclick="showSecond(this)" />Weight
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" id="volume" name = "rad1" onclick="showSecond(this)" />Volume
    <br />

    <div id = "div" style="display:none">
    Select Direction:
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad2" value="PG" checked="true" id="pTok"/>Pounds to Kgs
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad2" value="KP" id="kTop" />Kgs to Pounds
    <br />
    Number to be converted: <input type = "text"  id="weightAmount" name = "amount" />
    <br />
    <input type = "button" id="weightCalculate" value = "calculate" onclick = "Calc(this)"       />
    <br />
    Result: <br />
    <input type ="text" id="weightFin" name ="fin" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
    </div>

    <div id = "div1" style="display:none">
    Select Direction:
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad3" value="FM"  checked="true" id="fTom" />Feet to meters
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad3" value="MF" id="mTof" />Meters to Feet
    <br />
    Number to be converted: <input type = "text" id="lengthAmount" name = "amount" value=""/>
    <br />
    <input type = "button" id="lengthCalculate" value = "calculate" onclick = "Calc(this)" />
    <br />
    Result: <br />
    <input type="text" id="lengthFin" value ="" readonly="readonly"/>
     </div>

    <div id = "div2" style="display:none">
     Select Direction:
     <br />
     <input type = "radio" name = "rad4" value="GL" id="gTol" checked="true" />Gallons to Liters
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad4" value="LG" id="lTog" />Liters to Gallons
    <br />
     Number to be converted: <input type = "text" id="volumeAmount" name = "amount" />
     <br />
    <input type = "button" id="volumeCalculate" value = "calculate" onclick = "Calc(this)">
     <br />
     Result: <br />
    <input type ="text" id="volumeFin"  value="" readonly="readonly"/>
    </div>
```

Then when you get this function call you find which is called and send it to be calculated depending on what button was clicked.

```
 function showSecond() {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
             div1.style.display = "block";
             div.style.display = "none";
             div2.style.display = "none";
         }
        else if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].checked) {
             div1.style.display = "none";
             div.style.display = "block";
             div2.style.display = "none";
         }
         else {
            div1.style.display = "none";
            div.style.display = "none";
            div2.style.display = "block";
        }
    }

     function Calc(obj) {
         if (obj.id == "weightCalculate") {
            var amt = document.getElementById("weightAmount").value;
            doWeightCalc(amt);
         }
         if (obj.id == "volumeCalculate") {
             var amt = document.getElementById("volumeAmount").value;
             doVolumeCalc(amt);
        }
        if (obj.id == "lengthCalculate") {
            var amt = document.getElementById("lengthAmount").value;
            doLengthCalc(amt);
        }
     } 

     function doWeightCalc(amt) {

        var res = document.getElementById("weightFin")
        if (document.getElementById("pTok").checked) {
            var ch = amt * 2.2;
            res.value = ch;
        }
         else {
             var namt = amt / 2.2;
             res.value = namt
        }
     }

     function doVolumeCalc(amt) {

        var res = document.getElementById("volumeFin");
        if (document.getElementById("gTol").checked) {
             var ch = amt * 3.78541178;
             res.value = ch;
        }
        else {
             var namt = amt * 0.264172052;
             res.value = namt
        }

     }

     function doLengthCalc(amt) {

        var res = document.getElementById("lengthFin");
        if (document.getElementById("fTom").checked) {
            var ch = amt * 0.3048;
            res.value = ch;
         }
         else {
             var namt = amt * 3.2808399;
             res.value = namt
         }

    }​
```

I would recommend you change the fact that you're using names to ID's. Such as lengthAmount, weightAmount, and volumeAmount...

Also, I added an ID to the weight fin and used getElementById...

EDIT: alright I did all the functions this works! o.O!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CTRFU/6/)

Comment: Alright so I went through actually made your html a page and linked my js file to it and this works for weight... You'll have to make your own for Volume and Distance but they should be easy if you follow the same format as for weight... Good Luck hope this helps!

PS. If you don't want people to edit the text inputs you could just make them Labels and change the innerHTML of the label to match what you want.

Comment: yes, that does help out a lot. but i still cannot seem to get the result to be displayed in the textbox underneath my calculate button. would i use a document.write()? and inside the parenthesis, do i put the name of the textbox underneath the button?

Comment: I wouldn't use document.write. What I did is I got the element that has the ID of the textbox I want to change and then I set it's value to the namt variable...

Answer (score 0):

```
    var displayed = div1;
function showSecond() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked){
        div1.style.display = "block";
        div.style.display = "none";
        div2.style.display = "none";
        displayed = div1;
    }
    else if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].checked){
        div1.style.display = "none";
        div.style.display = "block";
        div2.style.display = "none";
        displayed = div;
    }
    else {
        div1.style.display = "none";
        div.style.display = "none";
        div2.style.display = "block";
        displayed = div2;
    }
}

function Calc()
{
    var amt = displayed.getElementsByName("amount")[0].value*1;
    var res = displayed.getelementsByName("fin")[0];
    if (displayed.getElementsByName("rad2")[0].checked) {
        var ch = amt * 2.2;
        res.value = ch;
    } else {
        res = amt / 2.2;
        res.value = ch;
    }
}
```

your code have a lot of confusing place but i think this should work.
you should read more beginner tutorials

2012/3/1
I put all the edited code on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t7mTf/1/

Comment: yes, that does help out a lot. but i still cannot seem to get the result to be displayed in the textbox underneath my calculate button. would i use a document.write()? and inside the parenthesis, do i put the name of the textbox underneath the button?